# Pandas 'at' function misbehaving

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to add a value at a particular row and column but it is giving weird results:

[image]

After this when I again try to add a different value to same column, it is added correctly!!!!
[image: a]

Comment: Please do not post code/data/error messages as images. Post the text directly here at SO. I suggest also reading [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the first scenario**, `.at` tries to find row with index `0` and column label `('00', '00')`. When it is not found, it creates a new row with index `0` and adds a new column `'00'`. It treats the tuple as a list of columns and assigns value `34323` to each column.

**In the second scenario**, the row index and column label exist, hence the value is assigned to the respective cell.

For the first scenario, you can use the following for assignment-

```
df.at[k, [some_variable]] = 34323
```

This will treat `some_variable` as a single column.